# Google Mock: Can't set actions nor user SaveArg function

Tags: c++, googlemock

Probably I'm doing something wrong but here's what I got:

```
namespace CoAP
{
    class IUDPProvider
    {
    public:
        virtual void Start(int port) = 0;
        virtual void Stop() = 0;

        virtual void SendPacket(uint8_t* buffer, int length, IPAddress ip, int port) = 0;

        virtual bool ReadNetworkPacket(uint8_t** buffer, int* length, IPAddress* address, int* port) = 0;
        virtual void DestroyNetworkPacket(uint8_t* buffer) = 0;
    };
}
```

Which is mocked as follows:

```
class UDPProviderMock : public CoAP::IUDPProvider
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Start, void(int));
    MOCK_METHOD0(Stop, void());

    MOCK_METHOD4(SendPacket, void(uint8_t*, int, CoAP::IPAddress, int));

    MOCK_METHOD4(ReadNetworkPacket, bool(uint8_t**, int*, CoAP::IPAddress*, int*));
    MOCK_METHOD1(DestroyNetworkPacket, void(uint8_t*));
};
```

I'm trying to mock it in order to check what "SendPacket" method actually got in the first two arguments. The line I wrote to expect that call and copy the values into a buffer is as follows:

```
uint8_t* responseBuffer;
int responseLength;
EXPECT_CALL(udpProviderMock, SendPacket(_, _, requestIPAddress, requestPort))
    .WillOnce(CopyBuffer<0, 1>(&responseBuffer, &responseLength));
```

Whereas I have defined the action as:

```
ACTION_TEMPLATE(CopyBuffer, HAS_2_TEMPLATE_PARAMS(int, k, int, t), AND_2_VALUE_PARAMS(pointer, length))
{
    //const void* bufferData = (void*)::std::tr1::get<k>(args);
    //const void* lengthData = (void*)::std::tr1::get<t>(args);

    //uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[(int)lengthData];
    //std::memcpy(buffer, bufferData, (int)lengthData);

    //*pointer = buffer;
    //*length = (int)lengthData;
}
```

NOTE: Probably the code inside it is worng, but I'm troubleshooting if the call can be made first.

I can't compile the code above as I get the error C2440: The compiler can't cast from 'const int' to 'uint8_t*'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem, after adding things like a test case, a dummy `CoAP::IPAddress` class, `using namespace testing;`, etc. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Strange, I tried also to recreate a Minimal, COmplete and Verifiable example and ended up compiling on that project. Could it be some compiler flag?

Comment: I tried to comment out the whoile code on that CPP file and tried to compile with only my minified test. I could compile successfully on that very same project. So no problem on the compiler options.

Comment: I found the problem: During a refactoring, I got two varaibles mixed up. The problem was not on the thing I pointed at all. Sorry and thank you.